# Django filter and annotate confusion

Tags: django, django-models, django-orm

I have two models

```
model A:
   cid = ...
   rating = ...

model B:
   id = ... (this id is same as cid in model A. But no foreign key directly)
   name = ....
```

now I need the list of all modelB objects whose rating is greater than 3.

I also need the rating field to be available in the result queryset.

I have done the following,

```
good_rating_A_queryset = A.filter(rating__gt=3)

good_rating_B_queryset = B.filter( id__in = good_rating_A_queryset.values("cid") )
```

Now I have all B objects whose ratings are greater than 3.

Now I want to retain the `rating` field from `good_rating_A_queryset` in `good_rating_B_queryset` so that I can serialize it and send to front-end.

I am using DRF to serialize. I want to access the rating like `good_rating_B_queryset.first().rating`

I thought I could use annotate but can't figure out how to map the field

pls help

Comment: Please use a `ForeignKey`, in this case it is even just a `OneToOneField` and you thus can use model inheritance. Why making this more painful for yourself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with @WillemVanOnsem, it is better to use OneToOne or ForeignKey when defining two interdependent Models. That's why relations exists in the Database.

Other than that, if you still need `rating` from another table, then you can use [`Subquery`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/models/expressions/#subquery-expressions) for that. Like this:

```
from django.db.models import OuterRef, Subquery

good_rating_A_queryset = A.filter(pk=OuterRef('pk')).values('rating')
good_rating_B_queryset = B.annotate(rating=Subquery(good_rating_A_queryset[:1])).filter(rating__gt=3)
```

Answer (score 1):

While one can work with a subquery, subquery often turn out not to be as efficient as JOINs, in fact MySQL is well known for example to have severe problems with subqueries quite often.

I would therefore *strongly* advise to use a `ForeignKey`, and in this case this is even a `OneToOneField`, so:

```
class A(models.Model):
    cid = models.AutoField(primary_key=True, editable=False)
    rating = models.IntegerField()


class B(models.Model):
    id = models.OneToOneField(
        A,
        primary_key=True,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        editable=False,
        db_name='id',
    )
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
```

then querying is done with simply:

```
from django.db.models import F

B.objects.filter(id__rating__gt=3).annotate(rating=F('id__rating'))
```

while this might take some work, you will almost certainly benefit from this in the long term, since it makes Django's ORM language more expressive with relations, and will prevent writing subqueries which are a powerful tool, but it is often hard to get it right and for some databases there is also a (severe) performance penalty.